# Creating a circle with star effect using 5 arcs(images)

Tags: html, css

I have 5 images and i wanted to align this 5 images like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You realise that if you show us your individual images we could give you an exact answer?

Comment: Yes, I saw that the individual sections (between the star's edges and the containing circle) were the individual images, but that shows me where they are in the final, assembled image. It *doesn't* give me five files to *work with* to assemble that image/collage.

Comment: @DavidThomas added all the 5 images..

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3 you can rotate.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_rotation.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should use [css transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) to accomplish this. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/d3W6T/1/) taken from the css-tricks [website](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly build stars and circles

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

With a combination of these techniques, it should be easy to put a star inside a circle.

The tricky bit is combining that with images. You need to use the circle as a container with `overflow: hidden`, then arrange the images inside, and cover the center with the star. img4 is a bit of a problem there, since it collides with img3 and img5. I can't think of a solution right now.

Comment: Thanks Pumbaa.But not creating star in IE-8

Comment: @Warrior: yes, but we can't show *precisely how*, because we don't seem to be able to see your images.

Comment: The images are 5 arcs of an image